# Add a character at nth place in TextBox text

Tags: jquery

I want to add a "." character at the 4th place inside textbox string.

Like if the string is "1234567", it should become 123.4567
Also i want to restrict decimal to 4 digits.

Please held in JQuery.

Edited:

On entering numeric characters (for this i have implemented a check which allows numeric only), after 
3 characters a "." should appear automatically.

Comment: Well... [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: is "." your decimal separator?

Comment: Furthermore you'd need to describe your "use cases" a little better. When do you want to add the "." (while typing, after leaving the field etc)? What happens if there are more than 7 characters? What happens if there are non-numeric characters etc?

Comment: jQuery jQuery jQuery ! People don't even know why they want to use jQuery, don't even know what it's made for or how to use it, but still want to. What you want to do can be done more easily and far more efficiently using native javascript. That's ridiculous... Have a look at String::substr() and try to use your brain.

Comment: For non numeric characters i have applied a check already. So one cannot type in non numerics. Also after 7 characters the textbox should stop getting values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/UdB4X/1)

```
$('#textbox').attr("maxlength", 8);
$('#textbox').val(function() {
        return $(this).val().substr(0,3) + '.' + $(this).val().substr(3);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/UdB4X/2)

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function() {
    var this1 = $(this);
    if(this1.val().length >= 3){
        this1.val(this1.val().substr(0,3)+'.'+this1.val().substr(4));
    }
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UdB4X/3/)

```
$('#textbox').attr("maxlength", 8);
$('#textbox').keyup(function (e) {
    var this1 = $(this);
    if (this1.val().length > 3 && e.which != 8) {
        this1.val(this1.val().substr(0, 3) + '.' + this1.val().substr(4));
    }else if(this1.val().length == 3 && e.which != 8){
        this1.val(this1.val().substr(0, 3) + '.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi tushar, whenever i delete any character in this textbox the decimal is appearing more than one. Any reason why ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```
$('#textbox').val(function() {
    return this.value.substr(0, 3) + '.' + this.value.substr(3);
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v8Qu9/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textbox').val(
    $('#textbox').val().substring(0,2) +
    '.' + 
    $('#textbox').val().substring(3)
 );
```